# How to send text from one Activity to another Activity?

Tags: android, eclipse

calculated.java: (this has to command to show the calculated.xml layout)

```
public class Calculated extends Activity {


   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.calculated);

   }
}
```

older:

main class:

```
 package com.barth.appie;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


Button button1;
String text;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton();
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoncalculate);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {

        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String text = editText.getText().toString();

             Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),    Calculated.class);
             startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}



}
```

calculated.xml: (this is what it has to show after the button press)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:text="@string/text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Furthermore I have `<string name="text">Value</string>` at strings.xml, and in the other class called calculated.class, I have it so that it outputs the calculated.xml ( which works fine)

**What I want:  I want to display text in calculated.xml, which is a string made in main.class, and i want the string to be the text filled in textfield called "editText1"**

Comment: Research about an amazing thing called 'Extras'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button button1;
String text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton();
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoncalculate);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {

        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String text = editText.getText().toString();

             Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Calculated.class);
             myIntent.putExtra("mytext",text);
             startActivity(myIntent);

        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
  }
}
```

***Calculated.java***

```
public class Calculated extends Activity {

TextView mTextview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.calculated);

       mTextview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

       mTextview.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("mytext"));
}
```

**calculated.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: But how do i convert a text input to a string?

Comment: Thanks, I added that to my class. But when i type @string/myEditValue, it says it doesnt exist.... how do i output the string in layout.xml...

Comment: Do you want to set the text back to layout.xml?

Comment: How do you mean? I want to display a string in a layout, and the string has to be made when pressing the button ( i think the string making works now, but how do i output it)

Comment: Also, my apps stops working when i add edittext and string myEditvalue at the top of my app... where shoudl i place them?

Comment: It's difficult to understand what actually you are trying to make

Comment: Please look at the other answer, he has kinda what i want, but the text doesnt show the string..

Comment: can you post your Calculated.java to post me perfect answer??

Comment: it gives an error at "mIntent.putExtra("mytext",text);" in the mainclass where "mintent could not be resolved" thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

> *To send the data from one activity to another activity*

MainActivity.java is first activity from where you want to send data to another activity.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Calculated.class);
myIntent.putExtra("text", text);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Calculated.java is second activity which receive the intent data whatever you pass from MainActivity.java

```
String text = myIntent.getStringExtra("text");
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textView.setText(text);
```

Comment: @Bart Now i post the get the text of edittext please check it and accept if its solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I added that to my class. But when i type @string/text, it says it doesnt exist.... how do i output the string in layout.xml...

Comment: I updated the answer check it but where you are using like this In edittext view in layout you should not remove line android:text="@string/text".

Comment: please post your complete code and clear the your what you want to do to move further.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help. Only problem is that it cant resolve "myEditText" and "context" i already imported the required things i guess.. Do you know what to do?

Comment: It gives very much errors. for example, why do you have setcontentview calculated, when we are in the main class?

Comment: If you planned to answer, Mitesh fixed it. It may not be the best way but at least i know how it works now. Thank you guys very much for the effort! I will mark mitesh as best answer, sorry