# Set text in textview from other activity

Tags: android

I have an `EditText` in one activity, and a `TextView` in another activity. I would like the `TextView` in the second activity to update depending on what I enter into the `EditText` in the first activity. All the strings for the `TextView` come from `string.xml`.

```
if (edittext.getText ().toString ().equals ("1")) {
    Intent Newintent = new Intent (this,Second activity. Class);
    Newintent.putExtras ("newstring",R.string.text1);
    startActivity (Newintent);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send text from one Activity to another Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052019/how-to-send-text-from-one-activity-to-another-activity)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
if (edittext.getText ().toString ().equals ("1")
{
  Intent Newintent= new Intent (this,Second activity. Class);
  Newintent.putExtras ("newstring",getString(R.string.text1));
  startActivity (Newintent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. Only thing that's left is to get the string on the SecondActivity.

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras!=null){
String value = extras.getString("newstring");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

you can simply set text in TextView directly for creating public static method when you are switching the activity,you can call method to set text in TextView in other activity.

```
if (edittext.getText ().toString ().equals ("1") {
    Intent Newintent = new Intent(this, Second activity.Class);
    Newintent.putExtras("newstring", R.string.text1);
    startActivity(Newintent);
    MainActivity.setText(text);
}
```

for example if you are defining method in MainActivity and want to set text in main activity than create a public static method in MainActivity and call it this method in other activity.

```
 public static void setText(String text)
{
    textView.setText(text);
}
```

this method will be defined where your TextView exist.

Answer (score 0):

> Answer by ahmed is right just adding explaination
>   Problem: String vs CharSequence

The first step in my understanding was to learn that TextView#setText() accepts a CharSequence whereas Resources#getString() returns a String and that these two classes are not always interchangeable. The reason we’re still able to pass a String is because it implements CharSequence.

The other implementation of CharSequence that we need to instead use is Spanned, which supports modifying the visual representation of text by using something known as “spans”. Spans are tiny objects that contain information about how a piece of text should be drawn and Android uses them heavily across the framework.

> [follow this link further details](http://saket.me/html-tags-textview/)